# Show that $T\boldsymbol 1_B+M\boldsymbol 1_{B^c}$ is a stopping time if $T$ is a stoping time.

Tags: stopping-times

Let $S$ and $T$ two stopping time w.r.t. the filtration $(\mathcal F_t)_t$ such that there is $M>0$ s.t. $$S\leq T\leq M\quad a.s.$$
Show that if $B\in \mathcal F_S$, we have that $$\sigma =T\boldsymbol 1_B+M\boldsymbol 1_{B^c},$$
is a stopping time where $$\mathcal F_S=\{A\in \mathcal F_\infty\mid A\cap \{T\leq t\}\in \mathcal F_t,\forall t\geq 0 \}.$$

---

**Try**

I try to show that $\{\sigma \leq t\}^c\in \mathcal F_t$. $$\{\sigma >t\}=\{T\boldsymbol 1_B+M\boldsymbol 1_{B^c}>t\}=\bigcup_{r\geq t, r\in \mathbb Q^+}\{T\boldsymbol 1_B>r\}\cap \{M\boldsymbol 1_{B^c}>t-r\}.$$

How can I continue ? I guess that $$\{T\boldsymbol 1_B>r\}=B\cap \{T>r\}\quad \text{and}\quad \{M\boldsymbol 1_{B^c}>t-r\}$$
and thus $$\{T\boldsymbol 1_B>r\}\cap \{M\boldsymbol 1_{B^c}>t-r\}=(B\cap B^c)\cap \{T>r\}\cap \{M>t-r\}=\emptyset,$$ so probably something is wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that when $r>t$ we get  $\{MI_{B^{c}}>t-r\}=\Omega$ because $MI_{B^{c}} \geq 0 >t-r$. BTW you also have to include $r=t$ in the union. The union is $B \cap (T>t)$.

Comment: Oh, I see, so at the end, we get $...=\bigcup_{r>t, r\in \mathbb Q^+}B\cap \{T>r\}$. At then end $\{T>r\}\in \mathcal F_r\supset \mathcal F_t$ and $B\in \mathcal F_S$. How can I conclude ?

Comment: Also, Isn't it true that $\{M\boldsymbol 1_{B^c}>r\}=B^c\cap \{M>t-r\}$ ?

Comment: When you take the union of $B \cap (T>r)$ over $r>t$ you get $B \cap (T>t)$. This set belongs to $\mathcal F_t$ because $B \in \mathcal F_s \subset \mathcal F_t$.

Comment: Did you read the part of  my answer where I said $MI_{B^{c}} \geq 0$ hence $>t-r$ for **every** $\omega$?

Comment: Oh, no sorry. I see :) Last thing is I don't really understand why you need $r\geq t$ in the union ?

Comment: At the end, if $t\in \mathbb Q$, then if $r=t$ then $\{M\boldsymbol 1_{B^c}>t-r\}=B^c\neq \Omega $... no ?

Comment: Yes, that is why I mentioned  that $r=t$ also has to be considered. But here you use the fact that $B \cap B^{c}$ is empty, so this part of the union does not contribute anything to the union.